# Include A 0 Count if null or blank in pivot

Tags: sql-server

I need to show data for each part, and my query is working...almost.  This is my syntax

```
Select * From
(
  Select item As [item], Count(sold) As [Count], StoreName
  From saleinfo
  Group By item, storename
)  first
pivot
(
  Count([Count])
  for item in ([brake pads], [rotors],[shoes],[drums]
) piv
```

Now the issue I am having with this is if their is a Count of 0 returned the item is omitted from the results.  Meaning if 0 brake pads were sold then brake pads is not dispalyed in my result set.  How can I have it dispaly the item even if the count returned is 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use ISNULL or COALESCE to *convert* NULL to `0`:

```
Select isnull([brake pads], 0) as [brake pads], isnull([rotors], 0) as  [rotors], isnull([shoes], 0) as [shoes], isnull([drums], 0) as [drums]
From
( 
...
```